# When my reward video finishes it doesn't give the user the coins.......Why?

Tags: swift, chartboost

Im using Chartboost reward videos and when the video is done playing I want to give the user 200 coins. I added the delegate function didCompleteRewardedVideo in my GameViewController but it doesn't give the user 200 coins after the video is finished being watched. What am I doing wrong?

```
     func didCompleteRewardedVideo(location: String!, withReward reward: Int32) {

    println("REWARDS!!!!")
    gameScene.coins += 200
    gameScene.coinLabel.text = String(gameScene.coins)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your function is calling when video is done playing?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes It prints the line rewards in my console when it is done playing

Comment: ok print this `gameScene.coins` and tell me the result. and check that your `gameScene.coins` is actually increasing.

Comment: It prints out gameScene.coins in the console and it doesn't add the coins.

Comment: ok try this: `gameScene.coins = gameScene.coins + 200`

Comment: do i use println(")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your delegate function `GameViewController` instead of doing that call your function into your `GameScene` where your coins are. and it will add and save it.